# Using waypoint jQuery to fade in header nav

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

Warning: Beginner with jQuery...

I'm trying to make my header fade in and out depending of where the scroll is at in this [parallax web site](http://egelect.com/2013) I'm working on. The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to make it ease in/out.

And I'm using a combination of [Stellar jQuery plugin + waypoint](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/) to make this new site.

On load, I added the "hidden" that puts the opacity: 0 .

Here a snippet of the nav :

```
<header class="navContainer">
<nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="logoMenu" data-slide="1"><a><img id="logoEGmenu" src="images/eg-logo-menu.png" alt="Logo des Entreprises d'électricité EG ltée"></a></li>
        <li class="text" data-slide="2"><a>Accueil</a></li>
        <li class="text" data-slide="3"><a>Services</a></li>
        <li class="text" data-slide="4"><a>Maître électricien</a></li>
        <li class="text" data-slide="5"><a>Projets</a></li>
        <li class="text" data-slide="6"><a>LEED</a></li>
        <li class="text" data-slide="7"><a>Notre mission</a></li>
        <li class="text" data-slide="8"><a>Nos experts</a></li>
        <li class="text" data-slide="9"><a>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="logoBG">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="navBG">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="noiseBG">&nbsp;</div>
```

Here's a snippet of the .js :

```
    // Fade in Nav
$('.navContainer').addClass('hidden');
$.waypoints.settings.scrollThrottle = 25;
$('.navContainer').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $('.navContainer').toggleClass('hidden', direction === "up");

}, {
    offset: '-100%'
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Manage to take care of it...

I've removed the .addclass and change the css.